# Generate many curl commands through binary file

Tags: python, linux, download, pickle, binaryfiles

I have a binary data file called `image_info_binary.data`, and I'd like to download many FITS images based on the information in the lines of this file. If I load this file into Python with the `pickle` module and print a single element, I get this:

```
import pickle
with open('image_info_binary', 'rb') as f:
    img_info = pickle.load(f)
print(img_info[0])
```

Outputs this string:

> ```
> Object #: 2000073.0
> Counter #: 2
> Scan ID: 0245
> Frame #: 167
> Band #: 3
> Image Link: http://....fits... #long url
> ```

There are about 50,000 of these elements, each with different object #, counter #, fits image URL, etc. I would like to go through each of these elements and download each FITS image as: `{int(object number)}_{three digit counter}_w{band}.fits`.

For example, I would want the downloaded image of the above example to be `2000073_002_w3.fits`.

What is the best way to do this? I know if I was just downloading one image I could simply execute `curl -o 2000073_002_w3.fits "url"`, for example. I'm not sure if generating many of these curl statements is the best way to do this or not. If I could just run a command in the terminal, that'd be great, but I could also use Python (but I feel like a subprocess would probably be slow). Thank you!

Comment: What's the type of `img_info[0]`? Is it an object with attributes you can access? What are its methods? Taking it from there should be trivial.

Comment: It is a string type. I could use regex on each element to generate a curl statement, but this just seems a bit inefficient, so I'm wondering if there's a better way

Comment: That sucks, but I don't think there is an obviously better solution. A regex is going to be painful to debug if you don't get it exactly right immediately, and probably less efficient than simply splitting the string into successively smaller parts and picking out the ones you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the URLs by iterating over the objects and splitting them into parts.

```
for img in img_info:
    attr = dict()
    for line in img.split('\n'):
        key, value = line.split(': ', 1)
        attr[key] = value
    filename = '{0}_{1:03}_w{2}.fits'.format(
        attr['Object #'], attr['Counter #'], attr['Band #'])
    url = attr['Image Link']
```

You can then print these, or pass them to `subprocess.run(['curl', '-o', filename, url], check=True)` or download them natively in Python.